# NextAuth refreshing or recognizing expired token from Azure AD

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth

I am having some issues where I can correctly auth to Azure AD and make requests. Azure AD has a token expiration of 1 hour. Once the token expires, my `GateKeeper` is not recognizing that the token is expired. So the page is served, but any API requests `401`

Right now I'm not bothered too much with figuring out if refresh tokens work, but just that I can't get NextAuth to recognize that the token is expired.

So, is this the right flow to be using and are there any obvious oversights when I am initially authorizing the client.

What I expect to happen is that a user is auth'd, once the token expires it tries to refresh the token, if it is unable to refresh it renders the `SignIn` component.

**GateKeeper.js**

```
//GateKeeper.js
// This component wraps any protected page from being shown unless a user is authenticated.
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import SignIn from '@components/auth/SignIn'

const GateKeeper = (props) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session?.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
      signIn(); // Force sign in to hopefully resolve error
    }
  }, [session, status]);

  // Important note. JS Date returns in miliseconds while the expiry is in seconds
  if (session && session.user && session.user.access_token_expires_at !== null) {
    if (+ new Date() > session.user.access_token_expires_at) {
      signOut()
    }
  }

  if (status === "loading") {
    return null
  }

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
    return <SignIn />
  }

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>{props.children}</>
    )
  } else {
    return <SignIn />
  }
}

export default GateKeeper
```

**[...nextauth].js**

```
// [...nextauth].js
// Taken from the docs as well as the tutorial on how to implement refresh tokens.
// Note that in my instance, the id_token is actually used to auth the user to API
// Services
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad"

async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    const url =
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token` +
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope: 'email openid profile User.Read offline_access',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      method: "POST",
    })

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens
    }

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.id_token,
      accessTokenExpires: refreshedTokens.expires_at * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      maxAge: 60 * 60,
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'email openid profile User.Read offline_access' } }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return true
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          accessToken: account.id_token,
          accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        }
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        return token
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token)
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user = token.user
      session.error = token.error
      session.user.access_token_expires_at = token.accessTokenExpires

      return session
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: i am actually implementing the same refresh token flow and getting same error did you complete this flow if so do help me.

Comment: I will see if I can dig up my notes. After digging I kind of gave up a little bit but I believe the trick lies in that ID tokens and Access tokens from AAD are not the same as Oauth Access and ID tokens